# Pull down resistor with 24v

Tags: resistors, pulldown

What is a good value for a pull-down resistor, which when switched, connects to 24v? Is there a formula to derive this?

This is effectively how it's drawn in the schematic (the inverter input's impedance is 650kohm):

[image]

Comment: That depends entirely on what you are pulling against - but you haven't told us that. Q1. What are you driving? Q2. What is driving it?

Comment: The 24V is switched by an opto-coupler, and fed into a high-impedance pin (650khm)

Comment: *"Is that a formula to derive this?"* Ohms law is probably applicable but we still need to know more. Show us a diagram.

Comment: Why 24V swing? This compromises the Opto which has very limited current GBW product. When you amplify from 1.2V in to 24V out you only get 5% of your CTR which may be < 0.5 already

Comment: @Oldfart, please see updated question.

Comment: If you are using a fixed 650K then fall time and available worst case output current are the limiting factors.

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75, the 650K resistor is just used to show the impedance of the pin which the 24v is fed into.

Comment: Why 24V?.............. pin of what?

Comment: The pin is an input on an inverter which needs 24v. The 24v is switched by the opto.

Comment: R1 can be any value that makes sense.  You just need to be careful that the power rating of R1 is more than the heat, P = V²/R = 24V²/R1.  What exact value makes sense depends on a lot of things that are not provided in the question.  But a 10k might work.  So 24V²/10k = 58 mW.  You could use a 10k ohm 100 mW for R1.

Comment: @scorpdaddy, what more do you need to know? I've provided an updated schematic (this time not making assumptions about how the inverter "produces" its impedance). This is really all there is to it.

Comment: You could add things like the capacitive load at the inverter input.  The presence of any EM noise in the application or vicinity.  The rise/fall times, pulse widths, and frequencies of the input signal.  The on-resistance of the opto.  Many, many other factors.

Comment: The opto is switched irregularly (on for up to 20 secs or so, and then off for minutes, etc). The idea is to be able to work with as many inverters as possible, so I prefer to be general, as far as things are concerned on the inverter side. I've got some 10k 1/4W resistors. Do you think they will be suitable?

Answer (score 1):

10K

10K is often a good choice if you don't know what resistor to try.

Simulate or think about the circuit with a 10K resistor. are the currents that will flow apropriate to the devices and the power-supply? will the voltages be good?
if not adjust it.

resistor choice for pull-ups and pull-downs is often not critical.

Comment: Yes, I think I’ll try it out with 10k. With 24v there’s only 2.4ma flowing which is fine.